# Magento 1.9: How to stop sending mails to a specific domain?

Tags: magento-1.9

Aim is to change the Magento (1) code in order to stop sending mails to addresses ending with "@specific.com". All other mails shall be sent as usual only mails to this address (ending) shall be blocked from being sent.

Comment: all mail or specific email (like order, customer confirmation etc..)

Comment: yes,all mail or specific email